# FullCalendar events not rendering / sticking / appearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I am trying to add events to my calendar (I haven't connected it to a database yet to save/retrieve events) and add events and have them appear temporaily. However, when I try and add an event, nothing happens and nothing appears.

The prompts appear and I can enter values in them, but the calendar doesn't update with these events.

My code is below:

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        /*
            Initialize fullCalendar and store into variable.
            Why in variable?
            Because doing so we can use it inside other function.
            In order to modify its option later.
        */

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar(
        {
            /*
                header option will define our calendar header.
                left define what will be at left position in calendar
                center define what will be at center position in calendar
                right define what will be at right position in calendar
            */
            header:
            {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            /*
                selectable:true will enable user to select datetime slot
                selectHelper will add helpers for selectable.
            */
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            /*
            editable: true allow user to edit events.
            */
            editable: true,

            /*
                when user select timeslot this option code will execute.
                It has three arguments. Start,end and allDay.
                Start means starting time of event.
                End means ending time of event.
                allDay means if events is for entire day or not.
            */
            select: function(**start, end**)
            {
                /*
                    after selection user will be promted for enter title for event.
                */
                var type = prompt('BAU/Project/Leave:');
                var title = prompt('Enter hours:');

                var eventData =
                    {
                        **start: start,
                        end: end,**
                        title: type + ": " + title,
                        allDay: true
                    };
                /*
                    if title is enterd calendar will add title and event into fullCalendar.
                */
                if (title)
                {
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // make the event "stick"
                }

                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
            }
        });

    });
```

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT:**

My events are now appearing as I have included start and end (as these were required) but I get the following browser errors:

```
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead. browserLink:37:40278
no element found
```

Comment: any errors in your browser console?

Comment: Great idea - never thought of this before. I got the error start not defined, so I'm assuming this must be required, so have added it it, the event appears but I'm getting a different error. I will add it to the post now.

Comment: is that an error or just a warning?

Comment: Use of getPreventDefault() is a warning and no element found is an error.

Comment: no element found? any other clues on where the error is..i mean the line number and file..

Comment: Nope - just says 25 repeats. It doesn't seem to be affecting functionality mind.

Comment: which browser are you testing?

Comment: just try once in chrome and see what the error is there in the chrome console..

Comment: Tried it in chrome and got no errors - strange.

Comment: that means they are browser related issues and your code is working perfectly..